# How should I handle multiple clients calling same method in a Hub?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, signalr, task, signalr-hub

As I am getting into SignalR, I stumbled across async/await Tasks. I have a Hub method that calls a Repository class, which calls the SQL database, to display/add to a list. However, I can't wrap my head around the fact if multiple clients call the method to AddToList, should I store each call to a List of Tasks? Or will keeping the method async/await Task without a List be good enough?

Edit:

I guess another question is, what happens when an async/await Task call to a method adding to a database, is called from multiple clients?

Comment: "what happens when an async/await Task call to a method adding to a database, is called from multiple clients?" - It just works :) Databases are designed to handle multiple concurrent queries. Is there a reason behind your concern?

Comment: Oh thats nice! I guess the reason is just more so of my lack of understanding of what happens. Another question: Now instead of adding to a database, how should I handle editting a unique item in the datatable with multiple clients? One of my co-workers suggested "locking" the item for Other clients and allow the Caller to edit.

Comment: Databases handle that for you at the record level. You can read a record before or after it is written, but not *while* it is being written. If you're writing to more than one record or more than one table, and you don't want people reading any of it during the update, then every database has the idea of a "transaction". If you're using Entity Framework, [it's already doing that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions#what-ef-does-by-default) (as long as you group all the updates into on call to `SaveChanges/Async()`..